# Up&Down vote arrows overlap with "First Posts" explanation panel

Tags: bug, design

When doing posts review, vote arrows overlaps with explanation panel when scrolling down. Probably, just simple z-index issue.

[image]

Environment: Chrome (Version 80.0.3987.132 (Official Build) (64-bit))